# Cannot read property 'concat' of null in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, concatenation

I am trying to get all data including parents & childs tp show with select2. I found an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/56be9zop/135/) which is useful for it. When I try to change "children" to "childPools", I got an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of null

```
 var FRUIT_GROUPS = [
            {
                id: '',
                text: 'Citrus',
                childPools: [
                    { id: 'c1', text: 'Grapefruit' },
                    { id: 'c2', text: 'Orange' },
                    { id: 'c3', text: 'Lemon' },
                    { id: 'c4', text: 'Lime' }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: '',
                text: 'Other',
                childPools: [
                    { id: 'o1', text: 'Apple' },
                    { id: 'o2', text: 'Mango' },
                    { id: 'o3', text: 'Banana' }
                ]
            }
        ];

        $('#fruitSelect').select2({
            multiple: false,
            placeholder: "Select fruits...",
            data: FRUIT_GROUPS,
            query: function (options) {
                var selectedIds = options.element.select2('val');
                var data = jQuery.extend(true, {}, FRUIT_GROUPS);
                var selectableGroups = $.map(data, function (group) {
                    var areAllChildrenSelected = true,
                        parentMatchTerm = false,
                        anyChildMatchTerm = false;
                    if (group.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(options.term.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                        parentMatchTerm = true;
                    }
                    var i = group.childPools.length
                    while (i--) {
                        var child = group.childPools[i];

                        if (selectedIds.indexOf(child.id) < 0) {
                            areAllChildrenSelected = false;
                        };

                        if (options.term == '' || (child.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(options.term.toLowerCase()) >= 0)) {
                            anyChildMatchTerm = true;
                        }
                        else if (!parentMatchTerm) {
                            var index = group.childPools.indexOf(child);
                            if (index > -1) {
                                group.childPools.splice(index, 1);
                            };
                        };
                    };

                    return (!areAllChildrenSelected && (parentMatchTerm || anyChildMatchTerm)) ? group : null;
                });

                options.callback({ results: selectableGroups });
            }
        }).on('select2-selecting', function (e) {
            var $select = $(this);
            if (e.val == '') {
                e.preventDefault();
                $select.select2('data', $select.select2('data').concat(e.choice.childPools));
                $select.select2('close');
            }
        });
```

I got the error on the following line where I'm concatenating the selection to the `select2('data')`.

```
$select.select2('data',$select.select2('data').concat(e.choice.children));
```

Any idea about this error?

Comment: Do you want to show all childs on the basis of parent selection?
or you just want to show only the parent and get the childs on click?

Comment: @SuhaibJanjua show all child on the parents

Comment: This is because you're trying to get "childPools" from a json that contains "children" instead. Why is it you are trying to get childPools? Where is that property coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting on selection of a parent is because you have disabled multiple selection which leaves the data property to its default value which is `NULL`. [Have a look at the documentation.](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) It clearly says that data property expects an Array of Objects when you have enabled multiple selection. By calling `select2('data')` will return a JavaScript array of objects representing the current selection.

Also you have used childPools instead of children which is not allowed by the API documentation. API is expecting following requirements in the JSON that is being passed to the Select2 method.

> When options are to be generated in `<optgroup>` sections; options should be nested under the `children` key of each group object. The label for the group should be specified as the `text` property on the group's corresponding data object.
>
> Select2 requires that each object contain an `id` and a `text` property. Additional parameters passed in with data objects will be included on the `data` objects that Select2 exposes.
>
> Select2 supports only a single level of nesting. Any additional levels of nesting is not guaranteed to be displayed properly across all browsers and devices.

[Click here to read API Documentation on Select2 Data sources.](https://select2.org/data-sources)

Comment: The problem is showing them. In the select view just "citrus"and "other" are showing so its mean just parents names are showed, what about children names ?

Comment: If you want to use `childPools` instead of `children` that will only work if you download the select2.js file and change the keyword `children` to `childPools`. That's not easy in a minified js file. So, you should use what API supports and expects you to provide it as input JSON.